In a SliverAppBar() how can I vertically centre the leading and actions widgets?
I have a SliverAppBar() within a CustomScrollView(). My SliverAppBar is used to collapse (and hide if screen height <900) the title and background image as the user scrolls. This works well.
What I can't work out is how to vertically centre the leading and actions IconButtons, so that they always stay centred regardless of the expanded or compressed height of the entire AppBar.
What I have (expanded & collapsed):
When expanded the IconButtons are not vertically centred, maintaining a fixed position regardless of appbar height.


What I want:
(expanded AppBar with centred IconButtons)

What I've tried without success:

Wrapping the IconButtons in Align() & Center() widgets.
Using a Column with MainAxisAlignment.center and MainAxisSize.max.
Dynamically adding vertical padding to the IconButtons using LayoutBuilder() to calculate double topPadding = (constraints.maxHeight - 56) / 2 then applying this to the IconButton.

I'm at a loss - what am I missing?
AppBar code:
SliverAppBar(
  pinned: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height > 900 ? true : false,
  snap: true,
  floating: true,
  expandedHeight: 80.0,
  stretchTriggerOffset: 300.0,
  flexibleSpace: 
    FlexibleSpaceBar(
      title: Text('app title',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge!.copyWith(color: Colors.white)),
      centerTitle: true,
      background: Image.asset(
        'assets/images/star-background.png',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
      )),
  leading:
    // THIS NEEDS TO BE VERTICALLY CENTERED
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
      onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
    ),
  actions: <Widget>[
    if (!userController.isLoggedIn())
      // THIS NEEDS TO BE VERTICALLY CENTERED
      IconButton(
        // Log in button
        icon: const Icon(Icons.login),
        tooltip: 'Log in',
        onPressed: () => Get.toNamed(AppLinks.LOGIN),
      ),
    if (userController.isLoggedIn())
      // THIS NEEDS TO BE VERTICALLY CENTERED
      IconButton(
        // Saved docs button
        icon: const Icon(Icons.bookmark),
        tooltip: 'Saved documents',
        onPressed: () => Get.toNamed(AppLinks.SAVED),
      ),
  ],
)),



Can you try toolbarHeight:yourAppBarHeight

Unfortunately specifying toolbarHeight then prevents the collapse/shrinking of the SliverAppBar on scroll (also doesn't lead to centering of the icons). Thanks though!

I'm starting to think that the solution might be to not use leading or actions at all, and instead use a Row with spaceBetween in the FlexibleSpaceBar-title: and just include my IconButtons there either side of the title...

you can also use  SliverPersistentHeader
